# Where to find explanation of kernel processes?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, documentation

I want to know about kernel processes, like `[migration]`, `[kswapd]`, etc.  Where are kernel processes like these documented?

Comment: I don't know if there is such a thing. They're used fairly extensively inside the kernel, there are a *lot* of different ones. Some are even, for example, specific to a single driver. Some documentation is scattered across the kernel documentation tree. Google can often help.

Comment: Have you gone through Kernel_source_code/Documentation ?

Answer (score 4):

I really doubt that there is a single place where you can find all the details.
Best way would be to browse the kernel source code along with online help and

**[Professional Linux Kernel Architecture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470343435)** (link to Amazon) by Wolfgang Mauerer provides information about a few daemons:

1. kswapd(Chap. 18)
2. softirq (Chap 14)
3. migration (Chap 2)...

**[Understanding the Virtual Memory Manager](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~mel/projects/vm/guide/pdf/understand.pdf)** (free) by Gorman also provides in-depth details about kswapd.

Answer (score 1):

The only book I found after a quick search is "Linux" from Michael Koffler. But from what I found on Google Books is does not explain this in depth (just name and what the daemon is for).

Answer (score 1):

There is a book called `Linux Kernel Development` by `Robert Love`. He is a linux expert and works with google, I've found the pdf book available free for download via google servers. It has some very good information about linux kernel, will be helpful to you.